# Using ID as a rangevalidator value ASP

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've been working on a small game and I'm stuck trying to figure out how I can convert an ID that a user enters to become an integer value. I'm wanting to create a rangeValidator that specifies that a bet entered by a user can only go from 0 to the total amount of money they currently have.

```
current money:  <asp:label ID="currentMoney" runat="server" Text=""></asp:label>  <br />

                Place bet: <asp:textbox ID="bet" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="bet" runat="server" ErrorMessage="bet must be less than or equal to current money">  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="bet" type="Integer" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="currentMoney" ></asp:RangeValidator>
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to convert the currentMoney ID which gets originally entered by a user at an earlier part of my code to be used as the maximum value for my range validator. Is there any suggestions anyone might have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to set the MaximumValue property in code:

```
RangeValidator2.MaximumValue = currentMoney.Text
```

As long as everything happens on the server.  If not, then you'd have to update the client API; if you do that, when a postback happens, you'd have to update on the server or update on the client again (as these are not sent back to the server).  I'm not quite sure how to do that, but googling should provide a solution.